# how to get rid of DB statements brackets

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

HOW can I display the values from Database using DB statements without brackets ?

```
public function user($id)
{
   $users=users::find($id);
   $name = DB::table('users')->where('id', $users->id)->pluck('name');
}
```

it displays:

> name ["alex"]

how can i display the name without the brackets

Comment: $user = DB::table('users')->where('id', $users->id)->first('); $name = $user->name;

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
$name = DB::table('users')->where('id', $users->id)->pluck('name');
```

you are getting an array.

You can just use:

```
$name = DB::table('users')->where('id', $users->id)->first()->name;
```

Of course I don't know if the whole code you presented is just test, but you could use:

```
$users=users::find($id);
$name = $users->name;
```

instead.

Also I recommend you to use valid names for variables/classes and valid case for classes, normally it should be rather like this:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$name = $user->name;
```

Comment: you'r right thanks @Marcin Nabialek
it worked perfectly.
but I'm still wondering how to get rid of the DB brackets in the front page ?